# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')" - Issues when using a separate search box to move a MapBox GL map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am currently learning how to create web apps with React and I am trying to utilize the MapBox API but I am running into trouble. The page loads fine, with the map centered on the coordinates I want and the search bar above it. When I try to search something, I am getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')". I believe it has something to do with the way the geocoder.query is working, but I am not 100% sure.

Can anyone help and provide some tips on how to better implement this? Code is below.

Mapbox component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MapBoxSearchBox = ({ map, onSearch }) => {
    // Create a state variable to store the input value
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    // Function to handle input changes
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    };

    // Function to handle form submission
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // You can perform actions with the input value here
        //
        //

        onSearch(inputValue)

        // Reset form
        setInputValue("");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="search-container">
                <input
                    className="search-input"
                    type="text"
                    value={inputValue}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
                <button className="search-button" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MapBoxSearchBox;
```

App.js:

```
import MapBoxSearchBox from "./components/MapBoxSearchBox";
import MapboxGeocoder from "mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import mapboxgl from "!mapbox-gl"; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

mapboxgl.accessToken =
    "MY ACCESS TOKEN IS HERE";

function App() {
    const mapContainer = useRef(null);
    const map = useRef(null);

    const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([-74.006, 40.7128]);
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once

        map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current,
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: zoom,
        });

        map.current.on("move", () => {
            setMapCenter([
                map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4),
                map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4),
            ]);
            setZoom(map.current.getZoom().toFixed(2));
        });
    });

    const handleSearch = (location) => {

        console.log(location)
        // Use Mapbox Geocoding API or another geocoding service
        // to convert the location query to coordinates
        const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken:
                "MY ACCESS TOKEN IS HERE",
        });


        geocoder.query(location, (result) => {
            if (result && result.features.length > 0) {
                // Extract the coordinates from the geocoding result
                const coordinates = result.features[0].center;

                // Update the map center with the new coordinates
                setMapCenter(coordinates);
            } else {
                // Handle the case when no results are found
                console.error("Location not found.");
                // You can display an error message to the user here
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <MapBoxSearchBox map={map.current} onSearch={handleSearch} />
            <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
            <div className="sidebar">
                Coordinates: {mapCenter} | Zoom: {zoom}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Wanted to see the map move to the desired location when searched, but it is throwing an error instead.